# How do you quote a quote?

Tags: style, technical-writing, grammar, mla, quotes

There's this sentence from Marie Kondo’s book, The Life-Changing Magic of Tidying Up: The Japanese Art of Decluttering and Organizing that I want to use as a title of my project, and I'm not sure if I properly quoted it.

This is the sentence I want to use:

**"Does this spark joy?" If it does, keep it. If not, dispose of it.**

Is this quotation below correct?

**"'Does this spark joy?' If it does, keep it. If not, dispose of it."**

Please help, thank you~

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice, especially after only a few hours. This site isn't as active as it used to be, but just be patient and you should still receive an answer.

Comment: Thank you!! Got it =)! So from my understanding, what I had corrected in the second bolded option above is right?
(Double quotation, then single quotation of the original quote, and then end the whole thing with double quotation?) Thank you!!